# date format - Regional settings - Months in lowercase

Tags: php, date, drupal

I'm a noob (I confess it) and can't manage to find a solution to my problem.

I'm setting up the date format on Drupal and it uses the PHP date format.

Right now it's "d F Y", so it appears as 07 Dicembre 2021 (in Italian), but in Italian months are written out in lowercase. Is there a way to transform Dicembre into dicembre? I couldn't find a proper way.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you could provide slightly more information about the code, we might be able to work it out for you, and give you a complete code, (what can you provide to us from what you can edit inside the code?).

Comment: Try changing `'F'` to `'M'` it will most probably display months with their respective first 3 characters. For example `'December'` will be displayed as `'Dec'` so then you can make sure that the problem is script-sided and not option sided. So simply, change those 2 and check if `December` is displayed as `"Dec"` and not as `"DEC"`, if it is still displayed as Uppercase then you will have to edit the script behind this form.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strtolower()` the output will be as you expected:

```
<?php echo strtolower(date("M"),2);?>
```

So to implement it only for Month, simply break the date format into 3 parts. Day , Month, Year.

Comment: it's not necessary to use 'substr' because  digits are not lower or upper ;) so it's enough to use  only  strtolower: ``` <?php echo strtolower(date("d F Y"));?>
 ```

Answer (score 1):

Use drupal module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter

Go to:

**/admin/structure/types/manage/[YOURTYPE]/display**

For your date field, click the gearwheel on the right (format settings) and **activate the checkbox for strtolower**

[image]

*Or create your own FieldFormatter: https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-a-custom-field-formatter-in-drupal-8/*

Answer (score 0):

You should use the locale aware strftime, which formats according to the current locale.

```php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT");
echo strftime("%d %B %Y"); // 07 dicembre 2021
```

Comment: Also see https://3v4l.org/89BDb

Comment: Thanks, but I only have the possibility to edit the field shown in the screenshot :-(

Comment: Is the current output already Italian? Because PHP documentation for the date function states "To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date(). " See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php for formats.
Did you try to set the format to "%d %B %Y" in the text-field?